# How to build in product expiration in SQL?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table that looks like the following and from it I want to get days remaining of total doses:

```
USER|PURCHASE_DATE|DOSES
1111|2017-07-27|15
2222|2020-07-17|3
3333|2021-02-01|5
```

If the doses do not have an expiration and each can be used for 90 days then the SQL I use is:

```
SUM(DOSES)*90-DATEDIFF(DAY,MIN(DATE),GETDATE())
```

```
USER|DAYS_REMAINING
1111|0
2222|6
3333|385
```

But what if I want to impose an expiration of each dose at a year? What can I do to modify my SQL to get the following desired answer:

```
USER|DAYS_REMAINING
1111|-985
2222|6
3333|300
```

It probably involves taking the MIN between when doses expire and how long they would last but I don't know how to aggregate in the expiry logic.

Comment: With SQL questions, it's more useful to use SQL as much as possible, such as using DDL for sample source data; this is part of providing a [minimal sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Is the `DATE` column supposed to be a prescription expiration date? Generally, naming a column based on type isn't useful, as it provides no additional information about the column (that info should already exist as the column type).

Comment: Good point, I made the DATE column clearer in an edit. It is the purchase date of the doses. It's assumed the user will start using the doses right away and that one dose can last the user 90 days, unless it is expired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MIN is a aggregate function you want [LEAST](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/least.html) to pick between the two values:

```
WITH data(user,purchase_date, doses) AS (
    SELECT * FROM VALUES
  (1111,'2017-07-27',15),
  (2222,'2020-07-17',3),
  (3333,'2021-02-01',5)
)
SELECT 
    d.*,
    d.doses * 90 AS doses_duration,
    365::number AS year_duration,
    least(doses_duration, year_duration) as max_duration,
    DATEADD('day', max_duration, d.purchase_date)::date as last_dose_day,
    DATEDIFF('day', current_date, last_dose_day) as day_remaining
FROM data AS d
ORDER BY 1;
```

gives:

```
USER  PURCHASE_DATE DOSES  DOSES_DURATION YEAR_DURATION MAX_DURATION LAST_DOSE_DAY  DAY_REMAINING
1111  2017-07-27    15     1350           365           365          2018-07-27   -986
2222  2020-07-17    3      270            365           270          2021-04-13    5
3333  2021-02-01    5      450            365           365          2022-02-01    299
```

which can all be rolled together with a tiny fix on the date_diff, as:

```
WITH data(user,purchase_date, doses) AS (
    SELECT * FROM VALUES
  (1111,'2017-07-27',15),
  (2222,'2020-07-17',3),
  (3333,'2021-02-01',5)
)
SELECT 
    d.user,
    DATEDIFF('day', current_date, DATEADD('day', least(d.doses * 90, 365::number), d.purchase_date)::date)+1 as day_remaining
FROM data AS d
ORDER BY 1;
```

giving:

```
USER    DAY_REMAINING
1111    -985
2222    6
3333    300
```

Comment: This is awesome. I still have a problem on my end, which is my fault on the example, but each user might have multiple purchase dates with different quantities. Do you know how to extend your answer to that scenario? Since it is my fault on the example, going to mark your answer as the best, but any help in this expansion of the problem would be greatly apprecaited.

Comment: @MarkMcGown so user 1111 has a purchase on 2020-01-01 of 4 doses, and a purchase of 3 more doses on 2020-06-01. Thus  you want something like `2020-01 + least(365, (4 * 90)) + least(365, (3 * 90))` is the end_date. Now there are problems if there is a gap between doses windows.

Comment: I think I can just take the max of day_remaining across all the rows and group by user id as my answer. I don't have the right 'answer' for my rows so I've tested this idea today and it appears right.

Comment: I would be inclined to find the max date range per purchase batch, as you note, and then check that all batches "overlap" another batch (if they exist) to prove there are no gaps like `(A-D, C-F)` is good, but `(A-D, F-J)` is not good. and then you can pick the last date for each overlapping batch, and then pick the earliest batch. OR just ignore all that and just go for the last, and assume it's all good (not how I would do it)